# autocomplete in textbox inside same jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am modifying the content. Data is being shown inside `<div>` country, but how to autofill a textbox present in `auto.jsp`? I'm getting data from `get.jsp` and content of `get.jsp` is being shown on `auto.jsp` in country `<div>`.

`auto.jsp`

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
    <head>  
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
            var xmlHttp  
            var xmlHttp
            function showState(str){ 
                if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                if (xmlHttp==null){
                    alert ("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                    return
                } 
                var url="get.jsp";//goes to get.jsp
                url += "?count=" +document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
                url += "&secondVal="+document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
            function stateChange(){   
                if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
                    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;  
                }   
            }   
        </script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <input id="textbox1" type="text" name="name" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/> 
        <input id="textbox2" type="text" name="secondVal" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/>
        <br>  
        <div id='country'>
            Here Iam getting data from get.jsp
        </div>  
        <input type="text"/> //how to fill up this text box based on previous textbox 1 and textbox 2(written just above)?
    </body> 
</html>
```

`get.jsp`

```
<%
    String s=request.getParameter("count");//Got first textbox value
    out.println(s);
    String secondVal=request.getParameter("secondVal");// Got second textbox value
    out.println(secondVal);
    request.setAttribute("s", s);
%>

<input type="text" value="<%=s%>"/>
```

Comment: Please anybody suggest an answer

Comment: Do you want to return the value to the input name or second val, right?

Comment: ya..i want to fill up that last text box(in auto.jsp) by the value i am getting inside div country,how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your function `stateChange()`, you are changing the value of `country` there. So you can change this to apply the result to other element too, for example:

```
function stateChange(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;  
    document.getElementById("textbox2").value = xmlHttp.responseText;
  }   
}
```

Comment: ya i got the value but in case of multiple value, how i should edit in get.jsp?

Comment: Multiple values coming from the ajax or coming from the input user? Some sample here will help. And to avoid too many comments, can you update your question?